# Help understanding approximation of integral of pdf

Tags: probability, density-function

Assume that $f$ is the pdf of a continuous random variable $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then:
\begin{equation*}
    \mathbb{P}\left(X\in\left[x-\frac{\varepsilon}{2},x+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right]\right)=\int_{x-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}^{x+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\approx \varepsilon f(x), \quad x\in\mathbb{R}.
\end{equation*}

**My question**: How does one realize that the approximation above is true for sufficiently small $\varepsilon$?

Comment: Is $f$ cdf or a continuous density?

Comment: @Atbey The function $f$ is the density, not the cdf. Sorry for the misunderstanding, I've edited the post now.

Comment: That is just how we define integration. The pdf allows us to calculate probability in the range of the rv Instead of the sample space $\omega$ so just think of the right as the area under the function f is the same as calculating the probability  in a small open ball

Comment: If $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small, then since $f$ is continuous it is roughly constant on $(x-\epsilon/2,x+\epsilon/2)$. Or just divide both sides by $\epsilon$ and LHS is the average of $f$ over smaller intervals. (Not rigorous but hopefully gives the idea)

Answer (score 1):

Assume $F(t)=\int f(t)dt$. Therefore

$$\int_{x-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}^{x+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t = F\left(x+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right)-F\left(x-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right)$$

Now by expanding $F$ as $F\left(x+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right)\approx F(x)+f(x)\frac{\varepsilon}{2} + O(\varepsilon^2)$ and $F\left(x-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right)\approx F(x)-f(x)\frac{\varepsilon}{2} + O(\varepsilon^2)$ and using the first order expansion only, we get

$$F\left(x+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right)-F\left(x-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right)\approx F(x)+f(x)\frac{\varepsilon}{2} - F(x)+f(x)\frac{\varepsilon}{2} = f(x)\varepsilon$$